# Streaming .m3u8 format using Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, m3u8

Hi i developed the application to cast my videos to TV via Chromecast.Now trying to play m3u8 videos via Chromecast is it possible as m3u8 videos buffering is good and control is good compare to mp4 any links will also do i cannot find how to stream m3u8 using Chromecast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .m3u8 format is for HLS (HTTP Live Streaming). To play .m3u8 formats you need to host your media content on a server. Make sure CORS is enabled. Then have your sender load the url, where your content is hosted, onto the receiver. This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) has much more details and sample code. If the problem was with your application, check out the sample apps on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast) as a reference.

Comment: Do you know any public m3u8 stream that supports CORS headers?

Comment: If you're just looking for test streams, check out one of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing