# Chrome-cast with AVPlayer iOS

Tags: ios, casting, avplayer, chromecast, google-cast

I'm playing videos using **AVPlayer** in my **iOS** application, and now want to add **chrome cast** support.

1- As per [this](https://support.firecore.com/hc/en-us/articles/215091007-Google-Cast-101) link, we can view chrome-cast button when video is playing. Is it the same case with AVPlayer?

2- As per Apple's requirement, my videos are encoded and are in m3u8 format. Can we play that in chrome cast?

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to check this Google Cast [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers), it includes API libraries and sample application code to help your applications go big. These APIs are documented in the API references, and the sample code is discussed in the Sender Applications and Receiver Applications overviews.

To answer the question if you can play the `m3u8` format in the Chrome Cast, first, you can check this [Supported Media for Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) to know all the supported media facilities and types in the Google Cast.

Note that Some of these require additional coding or the [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player). See [Receiver Applications](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps) for more information about developing your receiver application to support these media types.

For more information, check these SO questions:

- [ChromeCast doesnt play HLS in .m3u8 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502173/chromecast-doesnt-play-hls-in-m3u8-format)
- [Streaming .m3u8 format using Chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851579/streaming-m3u8-format-using-chromecast)

Comment: Thanks KENdi. Checking them.